# Recovering 1-year-old deleted emails

Tags: outlook.com, data-recovery

I have hotmail.com online account.

I have accidentally deleted (permanently) my important emails 1 Year ago but I need them now so I tried to recover them but failed.

Is there any solution or possible way of recovering them?

Comment: Extremely doubtful. I mean, that's what "permanently" means, right? Microsoft probably doesn't even have the data in their backups any more.

Answer (score 2):

They *might* be recoverable, but I sincerely doubt it, simply because of how long ago you deleted them.

According to [Guiding Tech](http://www.guidingtech.com/16547/recover-deleted-emails-outlook-com/), the only way that you might get these back is by:

1. Click on the "Deleted" folder
2. Scroll to the bottom of the list of deleted messages. You'll find a bit of text that reads something like "Lost a message? When you recover deleted messages, we bring back as many as we can. Learn more"
3. Click "recover deleted messages" and wait while Outlook.com tries to recover the messages

If they come back, great. If not, then they truly are gone forever.

The [Guiding Tech article](http://www.guidingtech.com/16547/recover-deleted-emails-outlook-com/) also has information about a setting which allows you to recover deleted messages at all. If it's in the more secure setting then there will be no way to restore those deleted messages, but you can at least ease up the setting so you'll be able to do it in the future.